# Converting json to xml in PostgreSQL using plpython

Tags: json, xml, postgresql

i need to convert a json data to xml. the sample code is as below.

```
from json2xml import json2xml
from json2xml.utils import readfromurl, readfromstring, readfromjson
data = readfromstring(

 '{"ra:covered-product-agreement":{"login":"mojombo","id":1,"avatar_url":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4"}}'
)
return json2xml.Json2xml(data, attr_type=False).to_xml()
```

where "ra" is the namespace. but the conversion is not exactly happening.

the result expecting is

```
<ra:covered-product-agreement>
        <login>mojombo</login>
        <id>1</id>
        <avatar_url>https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4</avatar_url>
    </ra:covered-product-agreement>
```

with current version the result received is

```
<key name="ra:covered-product-agreement">
        <login>mojombo</login>
        <id>1</id>
        <avatar_url>https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4</avatar_url>
    </key>
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Thank you

**update:**

Got a working snippet:

```
import xmltodict
from json2xml import json2xml
from json2xml.utils import readfromurl, readfromstring, readfromjson
import json

sample_json = plpy.execute("select content from items"); 
data = readfromstring(sample_json[0]["content"])
json_to_xml = xmltodict.unparse(data)

return str(json_to_xml)
```

Comment: What programming language is that? This seems unrelated to Postgres (only related to your programming language and the libraries it offers)

Comment: This question seems to have no connection to PostgreSQL. You should use appropriate tags. But even so, you are essentially asking for someone to write code for you, which is off-topic in Stackoverflow.